# Fix sqlite encodings

Tags: sqlite, encoding

I have a [data dump](https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/dump/sqlite-latest.sqlite.bz2) (90MB) which uses incorrect encoding (windows-1252) in the text blobs. How do I re-encode every text field in that db to utf-8/something sqlite expects?

The [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_any.html) only lists a few encodings, all of them some kind of unicode. Storing windows-1252 text data in an sqlite database is incorrect.

Comment: That's rather vague. How exactly is Windows-1252 used "incorrectly" here? You can't really expect us to download a 90MB file to figure out the details, so supply us a sample.

Comment: @deceze: While I agree the question is not very detailed, I think it does contain all the necessary information for an idea about the issue: There are Windows-1252-encoded strings in an SQLite file, and the OP would like to reencode them to something else such as UTF-8. (It does not contain, however, any thoughts on how to solve the problem at least partially, AKA "What have you tried?" answers.)

Comment: @deceze sqlite expects all text to be in some flavor of unicode.

Comment: Maybe so, yes, but then the details of how exactly what has been stored where is still important. FWIW, I've actually downloaded the file and browsed through it, and indeed some of the data is screwed up. And it appears that some of it is screwed up irreparably, since someone tried to store, e.g., Russian in Windows-1252. So, mostly you'll have to contact the author if you want 100% usable data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite expects all strings to be correct Unicode, so it does not have any encoding conversion functions.

To fix the encoding, dump the entire database as text, convert that with a separate tool, and create a new database from the result:

```
sqlite3 old.sqlite .dump | iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 | sqlite3 new.sqlite
```

(This works only if all the text in the database actually is encoded in CP 1252.)